# React component state persist from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, use-state

I have a simple shopping site, with the data coming from a headless CMS system. I am using nextJS/React to build out the site. When a user adds items to the cart, I want to use firebase to persist the state, as the user navigates different pages. However, I lose all data in the state as well as firebase, when the user navigates to different pages. The main problem is I can't set the initial cart state to the firebase data. How do I solve this problem, so i can use the firebase data to persist cart state?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Layout from './../components/Layout';
import contextCart from './../components/contextCart';
import firebase from '../data/firestore';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    //any way to set the initial cart state to data from firebase???
    const [ cart, setCart ] = useState([]);

    const addToCart = (product) => {
        setCart((prevCartState) => {
            return [ ...prevCartState, product ];
        });
        firebase.database().ref().set(cart);
    };

    //componentDidUpdate => listen for cart changes and update the localStorage
    useEffect(
        () => {
            firebase.database().ref().set(cart);
        },
        [ cart ]
    );

    //componentDidMount => run the effect only once and run cleanup code on unmount
    useEffect(() => {
        //effect code
        firebase.database().ref().once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            setCart(snapshot.val() || []);
        });
        //returned function will be called on component unmount aka cleanup code
        //return () => {    /*any cleanup code*/  };
    }, []);

    return (
        <contextCart.Provider value={{ cart: cart, addToCart: addToCart }}>
            <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
        </contextCart.Provider>
    );
}
```

Comment: I couldn't use localStorage or cookie as I had hoped to because nextJS pages don't recognize document or localStorage during render phases (server render vs client render)

Answer (score 0):

The data is not updating because you are not listening to the changes in your code.
You specify to get the data once in the `useEffect` Hook , which only runs on the initial load.

To listen to changes you can implement it like this:

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
   starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

read more about it in the official firebase docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

I would recommend you to use a state-management library like Redux or even the Context API from React itself.
The reason for this is that firebase charge you for the traffic to your database (this is a bigger issue for the firestore db than the real-time db but still there are costs to consider).
With a state library, you can check if you need to fetch the data from firebase or if you already have what you need in your state.
Also if you can split your code up with the Provider Pattern, this makes it easier to maintain the logic while your application is growing.